# When using Youtube API to get JSON, which IP is used? Hosting's or user's?

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, ip

I use Youtube API. I made an instant search for Youtube with Youtube API with javascript request to get JSON format. Does it use user's IP or my hosting's IP to fetch that information? Thank you.

Comment: Depends on where you are making the call from.  If you are making the json request in javascript, then it will use the user's IP.  If you are making the json request from PHP code, then it will use the servers IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything done server side will use your server address. Everything done client side will have the client address.

If you're calling the JS from the user's browser, the request will be made with the user's IP.